# UIImageView Slide Over

Tags: ios5, uiimageview, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2

How can i create UIImageViews Slide over ? I have a button and two UIImageViews in both saide of the View, when the button is pressed two UIImageViews should be slide over the view from the Two side . Can some body give me a start ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:durationOfAnimation animations:^{
    CGRect imageView1Frame = imageView1.frame;
    imageView1Frame.origin.x += 100 //or whatever number of pixels you want to slide them
    imageView1.frame = imageView1Frame;

    CGRect imageView2Frame = imageView2.frame;
    imageView2Frame.origin.x += 100 //or whatever number of pixels you want to slide them
    imageView2.frame = imageView2Frame;
}];
```

Where `durationOfAnimation` is how long you want it to take in seconds.